# R reactable - applying multiple styles in colDef

Tags: r, shiny, reactable

Columns in reactable (R package reactable) can be styled with a list of styles, a function or javascript - which works if I want to use one way only.  How can these be combined (without rewriting the list, function or javascript code?

Example:

```
library(reactable)

list_style <- list(background = "#eee")

js_style <- JS("
    function(rowInfo) {
      return {fontWeight: 'bold' }
    }
  ")

fn_style <- function(value) {
    color <- "#008000"
    list(color = color)
}

df <- data.frame(x = 1:10, y = 11:20)

reactable(
  df,
  columns = list(
    x = colDef(
      style = c(list_style, js_style, fn_style) # This generates the below error
    )
  )
)
```

Error:

```
Error in colDef(style = c(list_style, js_style, fn_style)) : 
  `style` must be a named list, character string, JS function, or R function
```

Comment: Since this so package specific, it's probably a better question for the github site for that package: https://github.com/glin/reactable/issues. It doesn't appear to accept multiple types so you're really making a feature request. Since it can accept a function, you could write your own function to combine different styles, but combing JS and non-JS code will probably be tricky.

Answer (score 0):

```
reactable(
  df,
  columns = list(
    x = colDef(
      style = list(list_style, js_style, fn_style)
    )
  )
)
```

it seems that your style out of list, please replace those code with this reactable

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, including a detailed explanation really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: It is true that reactable colDef, style requires a named list as input.  But this change does not solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

So within a single colDef style, JS functions cannot be combined with R functions.  The R functions can be combined as shown in the code below, which works.

```
reactable(
   df,
   columns = list(
      x = colDef(style = c(list_style,fn_style())),
      y = colDef(style = js_style)
   ))
```

To combine all 3 styles in a reactable table, either combine into a single JS function, or use the `reactablefmtr::cell_style` function to access lower-level font functions directly from R.